# Mvc, php, symfony 1.4: formatting datas for view, where to put?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony-1.4

Lets imagine this architecture:

```
model: get record and joined records
controller: iterating through all the records, and doing some calculations, statistics calculations even formatting dates etc
view: show it
```

is it good? I guess not. But model only may deal with data retrieving - not formatting. Controller cant do that either. Where to do the "iterating through all the records, and doing some calculations, statistics calculations even formatting dates etc" part?

Comment: the architecture, that you imagine, is not MVC

Comment: I know thats why I asked how should it look alike

Comment: When you are working with Symfony 1.x, you should not be looking for "what is the *mvc way*". Instead you should ignore the MVC pattern and look for "what is the symfony way".

Answer (score 1):

Framework agnostically speaking:

- Formatting date is a view helper task usually;
- If you need calculations [e.g. a mean value of a list], you should define your own collection model, and provide it with methods you'll be using in your application, because there is chance you'd be using them in different controllers, and you don't want to duplicate any code.

Comment: Could you point me to the article which explains what are "view helpers" are? Because I have never noticed them in "framework agnostic" context.

Comment: An example, if you're using Symfony 1.4, is the DateHelper class that can be loaded with the `use_helper('Date');` command in your template. You'll be able to access to all these DateHelper functions http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/DateHelper

Comment: @antony, I assume, you have no idea what "framework agnostic" means.

Comment: @tereško yeah helpers are not part of MVC, though all frameworks I've dealt with use them [Symfony, Rails, Django]; but imo there is no _real_ MVC web framework at all imo, because there is no view-model connection - at least symfony describes itself as a "request/response driven framework", so purists are safe : P